# Удалить дубли из списка

Tags: python

Как из списка удалить дубли по id?

```
cars = []
for item in items:
    cars.append({
        'id': item['id'],
        'name': item['name'],
    })
    
return cars
```

Comment: добавляйте id в список, перед cars.append проверьте, есть ли этот id в списке, если уже есть - не добавляйте в cars

Comment: Подскажите на примере пожалуйста

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Отобрать уникальные по `id` `items` можно так:

```
uniq_id_items = list({item['id']:item for item in items}.values())
```

Т.е. делается словарь с ключом `id` и значением `item`, в словаре по определению не могут повторяться ключи, сохраняется только последнее значение при повторах ключей. Далее из этого словаря берутся значения и превращаются в список (значения словаря - это специальный объект, поэтому их нужно явно преобразовывать в список).

Answer (score 3):

В `cars` изначально можно не добавлять дубликаты: используйте вспомогательный список (множество, как у [Zhihar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/273314/zhihar)) для хранения встречавшихся id, и при повторе `id` просто не добавляйте словарь в свой `res`:

```
ids_set = set()
cars = []

for item in items:
    if item['id'] not in ids_set:
        ids_set.add(item['id'])
        cars.append({
            'id': item['id'],
            'name': item['name'],
        })

return cars
```

Или так:

```
ids_list = []
cars = []

for item in items:
    if item['id'] in ids_list:
        continue

    ids_list.append(item['id'])
    cars.append({
        'id': item['id'],
        'name': item['name'],
    })



return cars
```

Answer (score 2):

если важно и `id` и `name`, то можно сделать в лоб через `str`:

```
cars_hashes = set()

res = []

for car in cars:
    car_hash = str(car)
    if car_hash not in cars_hashes:
        cars_hashes.add(car_hash)
        res.append(car)
```

Comment: ТОлько проверка по id